# Getting error message box when textbox1.text is empty

Tags: c#

I have a screenshot of the error message [ibb.co/dmKd2o](https://ibb.co/dmKd2o)  . It's basically saying "the format of the input string is incorrect", and that error message only comes up everytime i clear textbox1.text.

Here comes the code:

```
/*This is located inside public partial class Form1 : Form*/
        double aantalgroep = 0;
        double number = 0;

 /*This is located inside private void Calculate()*/       

        aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        /* Wat er gebeurd bij RadioButton1 Checked */
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            number = aantalgroep * 8;

            textBox2.Text = number.ToString();

      /* I tried this but this doesn't work? */
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            { aantalgroep = 0;
            } else
            {
                aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }
/* From here everything is oke( i think ) */


            if (aantalgroep < 10)
            {
                textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
            }

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  The message is clear, you're trying to parse a string which can't be parsed into the target type.  So what string value are you trying to parse?  You might also look into using `double.TryParse()` to more easily handle error cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use `TryParse()` instead of `Parse()`:

```
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep);
```

This will set `aantalgroep` to the value you're expecting on a successful parse, and set `aantalgroep` to 0 (really `default(double)` which is 0) for an invalid string.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, this was the second day i was trying only this line haha. I was not familiar with `, out aantalgroep`. I think i tried tryParse before with how i had it but the `out aantalgroep` did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this line you get that error when the textbox is empty

```
aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

You need to change it with

```
if(!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep))
   aantalgroep = 0;
```

or just call TryParse without the if because the aantalgroep is alread initialized with 0

```
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep);
```

Comment: Don't even need the initialization. `TryParse()` is forced to set the 2nd argument to something since it's an `out` parameter. If parsing fails, it sets it to the default value for the type (i.e. 0).

Comment: Yes I was writing about it. I have a little preference for the if version though. It is more clear for me (opinion)

Comment: The last one did the trick for me as @itsme86 did. I don't know why it didn't work with the if statement. That still gives me the error

Comment: Did you replace both Parse lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
aantalgroep = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

will fail if textBox1.Text is not a valid numeric string.
Either catch the exception or use `double.TryParse` which will return a bool to tell you if it succeeded or not

Comment: I am getting 'No overload for method 'TryParse` takes 1 argument? `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep);` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        { aantalgroep = 0;
        }
```

Comment: That didn't work `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep);` did the trick for me. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think I mentioned this in a comment in a different question as well.

The two methods `double.Parse()` and `double.TryParse()` do two slightly different things.

### [double.Parse(string s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

This method converts a `string` to `double`, and returns the value. **If** the `string` does not represent a valid value that can be converted to a `double` it will throw a `FormatException`.

So, for example, if your string is something like "abc", or if it's an empty string, it will throw the said exception.

### [double.TryParse(string s, out double result)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

This *attempts* to convert a `string` to `double`. If successfully converted, it returns `true`, and the `result` will contain the converted value. However, if unsuccessful, it will **NOT** throw an exception, but will return `false` instead, and the value of `result` in a failure situation will be zero.

See below:

*When this method returns, contains the double-precision floating-point number equivalent of the s parameter, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or String.Empty, is not a number in a valid format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten.*

Now, looking at your code, it seems to me that you want to see if the value of a `TextBox` can be converted to a `double`, and if successful, do something with the value and else, display a "0" into the `TextBox`.

So, try to formulate in your mind what you need to do. It will be something like this:

1. Get the value of text box and *try* to convert it to a `double`. Use `double.TryParse()`.
2. See if the above conversion succeeded or not. You can use the return value of the above method and an `if` statement for this.
3. If successful, do what you want with the converted `double` value. The `aantalgroep` variable will contain this value.
4. If unsuccessful, simply print "0" to your `TextBox`.

It should look something like this:

```
double aantalgroep = 0;
double number = 0;

if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep))
    {
        // Stuff you do when successful.
        number = aantalgroep * 8;
        textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // Stuff you do when unsuccessful.
        // Something like textBox2.Text = "0"; ?
    }
}
```

Comment: I learned from your explanation, thank you for your time. But it didn't work double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out aantalgroep); did the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: Isn't that _exactly_ what I did?

Comment: Yes but it doesnt work if you put that in the if statement. Maybe because i am using a auto calculation function i dont know. The only way it worked was the way @itsme86 told me and i been trying things for 2 day’s so, i tried alot. But thanks for your time